# \afterpage not called after page break

Tags: page-breaking, hooks, afterpage, atbegshi

In this example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper,landscape,margin=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{afterpage,refcount,lastpage}
\newcommand{\testafterpage}{%
    \noindent{\Large\ttfamily NEW PAGE!\quad}%
    \afterpage{\testafterpage}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\testafterpage}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

the words `NEW PAGE!` should be printed at the beginning of every page using the `afterpage` package. For some reason, `NEW PAGE!` is not inserted at the second page of the document:

[image: afterpage fails on 2nd page]

Is this intended behaviour? Is it possible to fix this in general?

I am aware of the various packages like `atbegshi` that allow to add some content when the page is shipped out, but I don't know if this can also be used as a replacement for the strange behaviour of `afterpage`.

Comment: I can't see the problem you're mentioning and get “NEW PAGE” on top of page 2.

Comment: @egreg: Really? I obtain a 4-page output, with `NEW PAGE!` at the top op pages 1, 3 & 4.

Comment: @Werner Add an empty line before `\end{document}`. The problem is that only paragraph endings trigger the page builder.

Comment: @egreg: I see. Since I use [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) more often and it inserts `\par` by default.

Comment: Ok, but adding a `\par` doesn't help if I use, say, `\blindtext[5]` since there is no paragraph ending for more than one page of the output. After LaTeX called `\shipout`, there should be a list of the remaining content to be typeset on subsequent pages. Is there any possibility to modify this content or at least prepending something to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\testafterpage}{%
    \noindent{\Large\ttfamily NEW PAGE!\quad}%
    \afterpage{\testafterpage}%
}
```

Is definitely not guaranteed to add text on to every page.  The recursive call will add `\afterpage` at the point the page breaker was exercised to ship out the previous page but if more than one page worth of text had been collected then this is the wrong place.

`\afterpage` is an incredibly invasive, fragile mechanism: it's not designed at all to be used consistently through a document in this way.

```
% This package implements a command, |\afterpage|, that causes the
% commands specified in its argument to be expanded after the current
% page is output.\footnote{This is really a pre-release, to see whether
% people like the idea of a command like this. This implementation is
% \emph{not} particularly robust. This implementation does not work in
% two column mode, and can get `confused' by \LaTeX's floating
% environments.}
```

Comment: Ok, I see. But then the question remains: How do I accomplish the above task if  `\afterpage` is not the right choice?

Comment: @porst17 you can't in general add text into the paragraph run at the top of the page  (as shown in your NEW PAGE) with afterpage or anything else in tex, the lines have already been broken into full width boxes well before page breaking happens. afterpage can only insert something _above_ the text that has broken over a page, and if you want to do that in every page that is just the page head, as specified directly or via fancyhdr etc

Comment: My purpose was to *inject* text at the beginning of first line of a page. But this seems to be impossible in TeX.

Comment: @porst17 of course nothing is impossible (you can position every letter in the document by coordinate if you _have_ to) but you'd have to disable almost all of tex's line and page breaking and do it "by hand" as linebreaking is independent of page breaking so at the page break you just have a list of boxes of full width lines, you can not insert something into the text and re-flow the paragraph.

Comment: Ok, not impossible, but also not really feasible for the regular LaTeX user ...

Comment: @porst17 see section 3.3 of http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-1/tb106mitt.pdf we've been pushing for tex extensions to address this since the 1990's :-)

Comment: Interesting, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to materialize.